# How many distinct Boolean function representable by a threshold perceptron?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, classification, threshold, perceptron, neural-network

It states that there are 2^2^n distinct Boolean functions of n inputs. The question is, how many of these are representable by a threshold perceptron?

Would not the answer be all? I say this because a perceptron is the same as a hard threshold where z = mx1 + c - x2 and threshold(z) = 1 if z>=0 and threshold(z) = 0 if z<0.

Answer (score 0):

All, if the perceptron contains at least one hidden layer. If there is only a single layer, then it can only represent linearly separable functions (which exclude XOR, for example).